How do I uninstall brave web browser?
I need to remove brave from my system because it is causing errors. I am on a raspberry Pi 4 and on version 23.10. I have tried other similar solutions but they did not work. I also tried checking the app center but it does not work, as in it does not load.image of app center not working When I have been able to uninstall it, it errors out and stopsImage of errors trying to uninstall brave browser

use the opposite method of how you installed it. and why did you remove dpkg?

I looked at other forums and found that but it did not work and I installed it from a file, i don't know how to uninstall it from that

What file? Where did you find this file? Did the file come with instructions?
